# Unable toInstalling xlsx package in Rstudio. rjava ,unable to load shared object in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04, xlsx, rjava

```
> install.packages("rJava")
Installing package into ‘/home/unix/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 672577 bytes (656 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 656 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
configure: checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports static inline...
yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... yes
checking whether -Xrs is supported... yes
checking whether -Xrs will be used... yes
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking JNI data types... ok
checking whether JRI should be compiled (autodetect)... yes
checking whether debugging output should be enabled... no
checking whether memory profiling is desired... no
checking whether threads support is requested... no
checking whether callbacks support is requested... no
checking whether JNI cache support is requested... no
checking whether headless init is enabled... no
checking whether JRI is requested... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating R/zzz.R
config.status: creating src/config.h
=== configuring in jri (/tmp/RtmphqeUs3/R.INSTALL29e9145183b8/rJava/jri)
configure: running /bin/bash ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking Java version... 1.8.0_181
checking whether /usr/bin/javah actually works... yes
checking for target flags...  -target 1.4 -source 1.4
checking whether Java interpreter works... checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking whether JNI programs can be run... yes
checking JNI data types... ok
checking whether Rinterface.h exports R_CStackXXX variables... yes
checking whether Rinterface.h exports R_SignalHandlers... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating run
config.status: creating src/config.h
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rglue.c -o Rglue.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c arrayc.c -o arrayc.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c callJNI.c -o callJNI.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c callback.c -o callback.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fields.c -o fields.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c jri_glue.c -o jri_glue.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c loader.c -o loader.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c otables.c -o otables.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rJava.c -o rJava.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c tools.c -o tools.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o rJava.so Rglue.o arrayc.o callJNI.o callback.o fields.o init.o jri_glue.o loader.o otables.o rJava.o tools.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
(cd ../jri && make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/RtmphqeUs3/R.INSTALL29e9145183b8/rJava/jri'
make -C src JRI.jar
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/RtmphqeUs3/R.INSTALL29e9145183b8/rJava/jri/src'
/usr/bin/javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 -d . ../package-info.java ../REXP.java ../RFactor.java ../RList.java ../Mutex.java ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java ../RVector.java ../RBool.java ../Rengine.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
warning: [options] source value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
4 warnings
if [ -n "/usr/bin/javah" ]; then /usr/bin/javah -d . -classpath . org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine; fi
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rengine.o Rengine.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o jri.o jri.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rcallbacks.o Rcallbacks.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rinit.o Rinit.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o globals.o globals.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o rjava.o rjava.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/linux
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_request_lock’:
rjava.c:22:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_clear_lock’:
rjava.c:30:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_request_callback’:
rjava.c:39:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong) * 3);
   ^
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_init_ctrl’:
rjava.c:51:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^
rjava.c:52:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   read(resin, buf, sizeof(ptrlong) * 2);
   ^
gcc -std=gnu99 -o libjri.so Rengine.o jri.o Rcallbacks.o Rinit.o globals.o rjava.o  -shared -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm
/usr/bin/javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 -d . ../package-info.java ../RFactor.java ../REXP.java ../RList.java ../Mutex.java ../RVector.java ../RBool.java ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../Rengine.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
warning: [options] source value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
4 warnings
/usr/bin/jar fc JRI.jar org libjri.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmphqeUs3/R.INSTALL29e9145183b8/rJava/jri/src'
rm -f libjri.so
cp src/libjri.so libjri.so
/usr/bin/javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 -classpath src/JRI.jar -d examples examples/rtest.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
warning: [options] source value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: examples/rtest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 warnings
/usr/bin/javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 -classpath src/JRI.jar -d examples examples/rtest2.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
warning: [options] source value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.4 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: examples/rtest2.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 warnings
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmphqeUs3/R.INSTALL29e9145183b8/rJava/jri'
installing via 'install.libs.R' to /home/unix/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/unix/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/unix/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava’
* restoring previous ‘/home/unix/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp1rqpcH/downloaded_packages’`enter code here`
```

**************************** loading the xlsx package  ****************

> library(xlsx)
>           Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
>            .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>             call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>             error: unable to load shared object '/home/unix/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
>             libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Heads up: this might be marked as a dupe to one of the many questions found by [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=error:+unable+to+load+shared+object+%27/home/unix/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava/libs/rJava.so%27:+libjvm.so:+cannot+open+shared+object+file:+No+such+file+or+directory+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=9FO&channel=fs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfz82J0vbcAhUEDq0KHQzJBzoQrQIoBDAAegQIARAN), but I hope not; when I had this issue the guide [here](https://github.com/hannarud/r-best-practices/wiki/Installing-RJava-(Ubuntu)) worked when none of the Stack Overflow answers did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting `rJava` to work can be challenging. In your case I would suggest to use the c2d4u repository. Since you are using R 3.4, this would be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-cran-xlsx
```

If you also update to R 3.5, you could use the corresponding repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5
...
```